# What attributes are being matched by `git log --author`?

Tags: git

From the `man` page, I see:

> --author=, --committer=
>
> Limit the commits output to ones with author/committer header lines that match the specified pattern (regular expression). With more than one --author=, commits
>              whose author matches any of the given patterns are chosen (similarly for multiple --committer=).

It does not explain what attributes are being matched by the pattern. After some experiments, I found that it can match not only user's name but also email, however, I still wonder if there is any attributes else that can be matched as well.

Comment: By `git log`, we can see a line in every commit which says "Author: xxx yy@zzz.com". If the value of `--author` is a substring of "xxx yy@zzz.com", it's matched.

Comment: As to `--committer`, use `git log --pretty=raw` to see the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `git cat-file -p HEAD` in your command interpreter, you will see the raw contents of an actual commit (they are generally pretty short—four lines of header data, a blank line, and then the commit message subject and body).

One of the metadata lines is `author`.  Another is `committer`.  The `git log` selectors simply perform [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) matching on the name and email parts of these lines.

As [destoryer answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45820565/1256452), there are additional selectors for operating on the date fields—these use the committer date and deal with time-in-seconds to human-readable time strings conversions—and message text.  Besides these, `git log` and `git rev-list` (which are pretty much the same program<sup>1</sup>) have a dizzying array of selectors that can change which commits are selected based on the commit graph, including external names for commits (branch and tag names and the like), and/or results of comparing the source tree attached to any particular commit to its parent commit(s).

---

<sup>1</sup>The "top level" `git log` and `git rev-list` code is contained in the same source file, with different entry points to set different initial options and thus behave slightly differently.  The `git log` command is intended for use by humans, and therefore shows output in human-friendly<sup>2</sup> format.  The `git rev-list` command is intended for use by other programs, and defaults to printing only the selected objects' hash IDs.  By making "select some commits" a composable unit, Git provides every programmer the ability of writing *new* Git commands that select commits with just as much flexibility as `git log` does.

<sup>2</sup>*cough* Well, as friendly as Git gets, perhaps. :-)

Comment: I will delete my answer in favour of yours if you replace the reference to my answer with the few filtering options I mentioned.

Comment: @destoryer: I will if you want, but, why not keep yours as well?

Answer (score 0):

Besides author and committer, you can filter by date (with `--since`/`--after` and `--until`/`--before`), and commit message (`--grep`)